# Не могу "замокать" (moq) динамическое свойство Excel.Range.Value2

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Есть класс, конструктор которого проводит инициализацию локального объекта:

**RSZKmodelManager_201638.cs**

```
    public class RSZKmodelManager_201638
    {
        private RSZKmodel model;

        public RSZKmodelManager_201638(Excel.Range rows)
        {
            model = new RSZKmodel();
            int number = 0;            
            foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
            {                
                model.Exercises.Add(new Exercise
                {
                    Number = number++,
                    Parts = row.Cells[1, 1].Value2.ToString(),
                    ...
                });
            }
        }  
    }
```

Теперь в юнит-тесте мне хотелось бы протестировать этот конструктор и проверить правильно ли проходит инициализация:

**TestRSZKmodelManager_201638.cs**

```
[TestClass]
public class TestRSZKmodelManager_201638
{
    private IEnumerator RowCollection()
    {
        var row1 = new Mock<Excel.Range>();
        var row2 = new Mock<Excel.Range>();
        row1.Setup(x => x.Cells[1, 1].Value2).Returns("something"); //здесь VS показывает ошибку            

        yield return row1.Object;
        yield return row2.Object;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPopulateModel()
    {
        // Arrange            
        var moqRange = new Mock<Excel.Range>();
        moqRange.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(RowCollection);
        //Act
        RSZKmodelManager_201638 manager = new RSZKmodelManager_201638(moqRange.Object);

        // Assert
        //Assert.IsNotNull(manager);
    }
}
```

Среда на строке `row1.Setup(x => x.Cells[1, 1].Value2).Returns("something");` показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что свойство `Range.Value2` динамическое. Без этого я бы как-то "выкрутился"). Быть может фреймворк `Moq` не поддерживает такие свойства? Что-то прочитал про фреймворк `Rhino.Mocks`, но им никогда не пользовался.

Как мне правильно в целом замокать объект Excel.Range?

Comment: Текст ошибки конкретный пишите, просто "сбой" - недостаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас путаница в установке. В коде вы используете `Excel.Range` следующим образом:

1. Обращаетесь к свойству `Rows`.
2. У каждого `row` обращаетесь к свойству `Cells` по индексу `1,1`.

А в тесте мокаете обращение к `Rows` по индексу `1,1`.

Вам нужно:

1. Замокать возвращаемое значение свойства `Rows`.
2. У каждой возвращаемой строки замокать свойство `Cells`.
3. У каждой возвращаемой ячейки замокать обращение к индексатору по индексу `1,1`.

Comment: Выяснилось, что необходимо было сначала реализовать `IEnumerator`. Теперь проблема в другом. Вопрос обновлен.